# How to export excel sheet using node

Tags: node.js

I m using nodejs .

I want to export  JSON data to xlsx format.

I used  excel-export module by npm install excel-export but not getting right way to writw code ...

I'm also facing a problem that after exporting xlsx file getting error to open with ms office 2007

```
var express = require('express');

var nodeExcel = require('excel-export');

var stringify=require('node-stringify');
var app = express();
var temp=[];

app.get('/Excel', function(req, res){
var conf ={};
//  conf.stylesXmlFile = "styles.xml";
conf.name = "mysheet";
conf.cols = [{
    caption:'Name',
    type:'string',
    },
    {
    caption:'city',
    type:'string'

   }, {
    caption:'Age',
    type:'number'

   }];




var data = [{
name: 'juhi',
City: 'delhi',
Age: 20 

},
{
name: 'vaishalli',
City: 'noida',
Age: 21

},{
name: 'kaushambi',
City: 'gurgaon',
Age: 22 

},{
name: 'suresh',
City: 'delhi',
Age: 70 

}];




for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
   var buffer=[data[i].name,data[i].City,data[i].Age];
    console.log(buffer);
    temp.push(buffer);
//        
};

console.log(stringify(temp));


conf.rows=temp;
var result = nodeExcel.execute(conf);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Report.xlsx");
res.end(result, 'binary');
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

Comment: can you post your code please? Impossible to help without seeing your code.

Comment: i added my code please check it.

Comment: To notify any user you have made an update to your posts you can do it by tagging the as follows @user2263572 (@ userName (without the space)).

Comment: @user2263572   i added my code ....please helm me out

Comment: @Frakcool  thanks to correct me how to post question correctly....

Comment: @EDdy it's ok, most people don't know how to use the site when they start using it, but, if you want to learn more how to use this site read these useful links: [tour], [ask] and [mcve] while you get an answer.

Comment: Have you tried the following potential fixes yet?  https://github.com/functionscope/Node-Excel-Export/issues/16